# styling a html select menu

Tags: html, css, select, font-awesome

i am trying to change the icon of a html select menu using [fontawesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/collapse/) icon fonts. My code is as follows

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

my css is

```
select {
    position: relative;
}
 select:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\F150';
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
}
```

here is the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YdQka/)**

how do i do this? could someone please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with how browsers render select.

You need to put a label for the select, then put your css after the label

```
<select id="select-1" name="select-1"> ... </select> <label for="select-1"></label>
```

then in css

```
#select-1 + label:after { styling }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YdQka/9/

Comment: Thank you soo much.. one more question. How do i delete that default icon.

Comment: uhhmmmmmm... I'm not completely sure. I played around with css like label:after{ position:relative; left:-1.15em; top:0.12em; background-color:#d0d0d0 } and it's close to a match, but really needs a gradient and tighter height/width to cover the default icon. It's a hackjob. Maybe there's a library plugin that emulates a <select/> out there?